# Inherit generic attributes in Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, type-inference

Given the following `class` and `trait`, what I am trying to achieve is create a subclass with a specific type of its own i.e. `Engage` and `Event`. This is what I have as of now:

```
trait ATrait extends scala.AnyRef {
   val test: Option[String]
}
```

I am able to achieve the following but to not much use (since the class is `abstract` still)

```
// this is made 'abstract' by me (can be edited)
abstract class BaseSchema[T, P] extends ATrait {
  val test: Option[String]
  val data: T
  val parent: P
}

abstract class SubClass(override val data: Engage,
                        override val parent: Event
                       ) extends BaseSchema [Engage, Event]
```

If I convert the SubClass to a `class` or a `case class` I would have to implement all abstract members.

What is the correct way of dealing with this in scala? In Java, one could have done

```
abstract class BaseSchema<T,P> {
    T data;
    P parent;
}

class SubClass extends BaseSchema<Engage, Event> {
}

class Engage{} class Event{}

SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
Engage eng = subClass.data;
```

Comment: Well, it surprises me that **Java** allows that and even worse than the value is simple automatically overridden with a `null`. Is that the behavior you want in **Scala**? If so, let me warn you that is not idiomatic in **Scala**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez To focus on the primary question, the intent is to infer the type of the `data` and `parent` attributes. Pertaining to initialization, I would be happy with a way to assign some default values to those attributes in the parent class if that's feasible.

Comment: @Naman Scala requires you to initialise all non-abstract values. This isn't really a problem because most values in Scala are immutable and therefore need to be given a sensible value anyway. But even `var` values have to be intialised because most types don't have a meaningful default value.

Comment: @Naman The types are inferred correctly, something which has undefined abstract members, has to be abstract, period. Also, **Scala** doesn't have default values, because the only default is `null`, which is discouraged in **Scala**. It would be better if you could explain to us, what is your use case? What are you trying to do with this non-defined but concrete class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're not defining the implementation of `ATrait.test`. As this is a `val` it must be implemented to have a value; any sub-type that doesn't implement it must therefore be *abstract* (either a `trait` or an `abstract class`). This member is missing from the *Java* version of your example.

In this solution, I've given it a value of `None` in `BaseSchema`, as there's no indication how it should be defined. If you can provide an example of what that is supposed to look like, it would help.

BTW, in *Scala*, if you have an `abstract class` with no arguments, then it can be defined as a `trait` instead, which makes things a little more flexible, as it can then be mixed in as well as being a base class. Here's an example with that done (and note that `SubClass` is no longer `abstract`), within the *Scala REPL*:

```scala
C:\SomeDir>scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_222).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> class Engage
defined class Engage

scala> class Event
defined class Event

scala> trait ATrait {
     |   val test: Option[String]
     | }
defined trait ATrait

scala> trait BaseSchema[T, P] extends ATrait {
     |   override val test: Option[String] = None
     |   val data: T
     |   val parent: P
     | }
defined trait BaseSchema

scala> class SubClass(override val data: Engage, override val parent: Event) extends BaseSchema[Engage, Event]
defined class SubClass
```

If you want to make `SubClass` a `case class`, then this is the way to go; just add `final case` in front of the definition of `SubClass` (*all* case classes should be declared `final`):

```scala
scala> final case class SubClass(override val data: Engage, override val parent: Event) extends BaseScheme[Engage, Event]
defined class SubClass
```

Alternatively, you could make `data` and `parent` parameters of `BaseSchema`, in which case it must be defined as an `abstract class` (if you don't want it to be instantiated *as is*) or a `class`; in both cases, neither `data` nor `parent` are abstract. Both of the following definitions are valid:

```scala
scala> abstract class BaseSchema[T, P](val data: T, val parent: P) extends ATrait {
     |   override val test: Option[String] = None
     | }
defined class BaseSchema
```

or

```scala
scala> class BaseSchema[T, P](val data: T, val parent: P) extends ATrait {
     |   override val test: Option[String] = None
     | }
defined class BaseSchema
```

And you can then subclass either definition like this:

```scala
scala> class SubClass(d: Engage, p: Event) extends BaseSchema[Engage, Event](d, p)
defined class SubClass
```

Indeed, since the generic types can be inferred from the parameters, this can also be simplified to just:

```scala
scala> class SubClass(d: Engage, p: Event) extends BaseSchema(d, p)
defined class SubClass
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The part of your answer `class BaseSchema[T, P](val data: T, val parent: P) extends ATrait { override val test: Option[String] = None }` helps understand that I was missing the implementation and the syntax `class SubClass(d: Engage, p: Event) extends BaseSchema[Engage, Event](d, p)` was something I was not aware of either. It helped me resolve my current query.